# My Background Selector in RecyclerView does't work

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

here is my code in item.xml

```
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/card_item"
    android:background="@drawable/item_selector"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
    android:layout_width="175dp"
    android:layout_height="120dp">
```

and the selector

```
{
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item android:drawable="@color/textcolor_gray" android:state_pressed="true"/>
    <item android:drawable="@color/colorWhite" android:state_pressed="false" />
</selector>}
```

Comment: <android.support.v7.widget.CardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/card_item"
    android:background="@drawable/item_selector"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
    android:layout_width="175dp"
    android:layout_height="120dp">          it's the item.xml

Answer (score 1):

I found an answer. The cardView should set with clickable as true, because it's default is false. The following code should work (last line):-

```
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/card_item"
    android:background="@drawable/item_selector"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
    android:layout_width="175dp"
    android:layout_height="120dp"
    android:clickable="true">
```